# Connect O365 group to SharePoint Online team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, office-365-groups

In the past I've created some O365 groups (some with over 200 members).

I would like to create SharePoint Online team sites and connect to groups I've already made.

Is that possibile? It seems that creating sites from SharePoint Online Admin Center I've the only option to create a new site and at the same time a new O365 group.

Any suggestion on how can I connect a team site to an already created O365 group?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it's not supported to connect an existing site collection to an existing O365 Group currently.

You have to create a new group regardless of through PowerShell or UI.

More references:

[Connect to an Office 365 group.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-connect-to-office365-group)

Connect sites to new Office 365 groups using PowerShell:Set-SPOSiteOffice365Group

[Connect sites to new Office 365 groups using the CSOM API.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/groupify/groupify-csom)